# validation error and possibly strong parameters with "Can't mass-assign protected attributes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I am migrating an old app to strong parameters and a bit of a wierd issue has come up. I have a Location model and the abbreviated version is:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

The problems is that this name variable is giving me a mass-assignment error even when called from the rails cli. Such as:

[image]

But I'm not really sure why. Another model Comment is just fine (no validation issue or mass-assignment warning) with or without validations making me thing it isn't some installation issue but possibly somehow either a collision of the name variable or some other issue. Any ideads on how to fix this?

Comment: add:  attr_protected: :id

Comment: @ilanberci hmmm, why would I need that?

Comment: Which `rails` version you are using?

Comment: 3.2.19 - I know old version

Comment: Here the reference [Document](http://carreno.me/articles/how-to-upgrade-to-strong-parameters-in-rails)